# how to call assembly language instructions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, assembly

Is there a way one call assembly language instructions in JavaScript ? 
Basically i want to leverage [AES-NI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) from a web browser .

One route is writing C bindings for AES-NI and then writing JS bindings to call C . 
But is there a direct route ?

Answer (score 1):

In short: no. Browsers do HTTP, that's it. You'll have to bridge the gap as you hinted yourself.

Browsers are, of course, as pointed out in comment below, much more these days than what they were 20 years ago. They can deal with a variety of content. But that does not take away the fact, that they are still intended to be **user-level sandboxes**, effectively creating a shielded playpen far away from the world below. After all, you wouldn't want some malicious script to wipe your personal files or grab hold of your chat logs or mail archive.

Pointing out the obvious: there are always security concerns when you cut the fence but I won't go off-topic here.

Having said that, there are ways to play beyond the sandbox like ActiveX/COM, [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/), even [java applets](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076775/java-security/escape-the-sandbox--access-native-methods-from-an-applet.html) or Google's [Native Client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/?csw=1) are just some of the many ways to get to native code from a browser, depending on your needs or flavor.

Comment: Browsers do a lot more than HTTP, though (think of HTML, Javascript, CSS, images, PDF, videos, audio, SSL, websockets, localStorage).

Comment: You're quite right of course. It was not my intention to diminish the average browser to its core functionality. I will amend my answer.